# Security issues with PHP Sandbox

Tags: php

I am working on a PHP sandbox for a Web Application Honeypot. The PHP sandbox will analyze a PHP file that may have been injected as part of an RFI attack. It should run the file in a safe environment and return the result, embedding the output of the PHP script. We hope to fool the attacker into believing that this is a genuine response and thus continue with the next step of his attack.

In order to build the sandbox, we used the Advance PHP Debugger (ADP). Using the `rename_function` and `override_function`, vulnerable PHP functions have been rewritten. Some functions such as `exec`,`disk_free_space` have been rewritten to send out fake replies. All the others function just return nothing. [Here's](http://pastebin.com/Fd19QMRP) a complete list of the functions that have been considered.

Also, the input script is run only for a maximum of 10 seconds in the sandbox. After that, the entire sandbox process gets killed.

1. Is this list good enough? Does this make the sandbox secure enough to be made part of the web app?
2. Beside blocking function calls like this, are there anymore security measures that should be taken?
3. In the end, this is a honeypot. So, we would like our reply to be as close as possible to a real reply. So, by blocking DNS function calls like `dns_check_record` and `gethostbyname` are we restricting the scope of execution for the script unnecessarily. (I am not sure why they are present in the first place)

   In short, I would like to know what elements I should add/delete from the list.
4. Any other suggestions/advice on how to go about this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: How can you know the output of code without actually running it?  I guess you could do some extremely complex analyzing of the code as to gather the output in a roundabout way, but other than that?  And I know this isn't very helpful, but my suggestion is that you just don't do this.  If something accidentally slides through your honeypot then oops! Compromised server.  And that's never fun.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is necessary? Can't you just prevent the RFI attack in the first place? Or has this potentially already occurred and you're trying to verify that none of the code on your server(s) has been compromised?

Comment: Sounds like a neat yet very risky project. I think the only way to ensure a perfect sandbox in this case would be to have the actual honey pot on a different server (a vm perhaps to allow quick reloads) and have the actual server pass the full php script to the second server. This way if you forget something nothing serious will be compromised.

Comment: @Corbin: No, we are running the code. Its just that, for some of the risky functions such as `exec` or `fopen` we return fake output (such as when they ask for /etc/passwd file).

Comment: @rdlowrey: The idea is to let the RFI happen, capture the injected file, run it and hopefully capture more files if they happen to be downloaded by the malicious script.

Comment: Hmmm, definitely does sound like an interesting project.  I guess your best bet would be to find as many malicious scripts as you can and see what they do.  And as MitMaro said, you probably want to run it its own server (maybe a VM).  Wish I could help, but off the top of my head all I can think of is exec type stuff and IO stuff.

Comment: @MitMaro: This project is going to be distributed. So, we would like to make it easy to install. A VM might complicate the installation procedure.

Comment: @MitMaro Are there any light weight VMs that you can suggest? I would like it to very to easy to install and configure.

Comment: Did you not like the answers you got at security.stackexchange?

Comment: I first asked the question here, and later realized there was another place where I can ask this. I am still waiting for more answers though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's very hard, if not impossible, to foresee all the possible harmful function calls in order to fake their output (for example, highlight_file or its alias show_source are not on your list). Besides, using the same server for both the real app and the honeypot rises other concerns: does the app use extensions? if it does many more functions have to be blocked/faked. What if you update one of those extensions? you'll have to recheck for new security holes. Also, what if a malicious file is uploaded to the honeypot, and then accessed from the main app?? sure you will take measures to not allow that to happen, but if you have a bug at some point, the harmful code will already be on the server... doesn't look safe to me.

I think it would be better to set up a vm as **MitMaro** suggested. In that case, the VM itself would be as good as a sandbox as you can get, and without much effort you can let all those nasty php functions execute inside the VM without compromising the security of the main app

Comment: +1 Thanks for the example functions that you suggested. Also, I have posted a question on [Servefault](http://serverfault.com/questions/374663/need-a-vm-for-running-a-php-sandbox) asking for a VM. Please answer there if you have any suggestions.